# Google App Engine Blobstore not working suddenly

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

we've been running our app for a few months now and have had no problems. Suddenly this morning, all files uploaded to the blobstore can't be downloaded. They all download as a 0KB (empty) file. The old files in the blobstore that were uploaded before today still download without any problems. We haven't changed anything on the server or the app, we haven't even looked at the code in about 2 weeks, so is this a Google App Engine problem?

I checked the System Status page, which says everything is fine, but I noticed there isn't a Blobstore section on that page. How can I know if this is a Google problem or a problem with our app?

I've also checked the server logs, and there's nothing out of the ordinary...

**Edit:** I just checked the headers from the request to download a file from the blobstore. HTTP code is 200, everything is normal, except Content-Length is 0... When I look at that blob in the admin page, it says it is 123KB... Also, when I try to download the blob from the admin page, even though it says 123KB the downloaded file is still 0B...

Comment: Seems it's a known issue, Google is currently working on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blobstore is working again.  Downtime msg:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/1gX2vRtAPCI